# A little bit of personalization for beta pages

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, beta-phase

Even though I really like the sketch skin, I'm not sure about how I feel about having the exact same feel for every beta page, specially when several of them are running simultaneously.

I think this is even more important for pages that are on PUBLIC betas. Private betas are (currently) pretty much for experienced SE users and we are ok...but public betas are for all of the internauts out there... and and a sketchy-looking page that, except for the title doensnt really show what the page is about might not seem too appealing.

I think that pages could benefefit from a little bit of personality, even if was a little sketch-drawing and/or changing the color palette a little bit, dont you?